# How to use String array with multiple LinearLayouts in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I want to use String array as incremental of LinearLayouts as given below for background color change of 12 months JAN to DEC as per current month. But its not at all working as per below code. What i'm missing, please provide me correct snippet with an example.

```
String[] string = {linear_layout1, linear_layout2, linear_layout3, linear_layout4, linear_layout5, linear_layout6, linear_layout7, linear_layout8, linear_layout9, linear_layout10, linear_layout11, linear_layout12};
   if(monthOfYear <= 12) {
      for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) 
         {
            string.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GRAY));
         }
   }
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Please add error log and more context as to why its not working. What are all these linear_layout* data types?

Comment: Showing errors(red marks) at linear_layout* and at `string.setBackgroundColor`. These linear_layout* are `.xml` `id`s. I want to use these `linearlayout id`s with `string array` list to change `linearlayouts` background color. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

so as I get your question you have many Views which you want to change the Background color of them right?
if that's the case then your code has the problem and the solve is this:

```
LinearLayout[] lns= {linear_layout1, linear_layout2, linear_layout3, linear_layout4, linear_layout5, linear_layout6, linear_layout7, linear_layout8, linear_layout9, linear_layout10, linear_layout11, linear_layout12};
   if(monthOfYear <= 12) {
      for(int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) 
         {
            lns[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GRAY));
         }
   }
```

so first of all LinearLayouts are Views and you need to have an array of LinearLayouts or Views not String[](why String?)
the second problem was you are reading from the array so you need to get the object with 'i' variable you have declared in the for loop and get every LinearLayout to change and work on it.
and for this to be easier I have changed the for loop start from 1 to 0 and the end from 12 to 11.
(you can use for-each instead of for it will be easier...)
Any other problem? just ask.

**Edit**

Ok so as I think I saw your comments I think these `linear_layout1`,... are just ids from your .xml file. Right? in that case then your code should be like this :

```
LinearLayout[] lns= {(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout1),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout2),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout3),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout4),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout5),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout6),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout7),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout8),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout9),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout10),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout11),(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout12)};
      for(int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) 
         {
            lns[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GRAY));
         }
```

and I think that if-statement is useless too, cause the for loop is always 12 times so what is that if about? so I removed that too.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response with details. I have changed as per above code but app is crashing on activity opens without any Logcat errors.

Comment: yes of course cause the Linears are not clear that are just names and for examples. please add your complete Activity code for guiding you better.

Comment: Hi @Amir, code is working as below but there is one problem, 12 linearlayout backgrounds are highlighting instead of current ll month. Revised code: `LinearLayout[] lns= {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, l11, l12};
                                for(i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {if(dayOfMonth == i) {lns[inc].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GRAY));}}`.  I tried many ways to get highlight only current month but nothing worked. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: if this is your renewed code then that ```lns[inc]``` is the problem. what is ```inc```? you have to use ```lns[I]```.

Comment: Ok so then as I read from your comment at the above post I think these ```l1,l2,l3,...``` are just ids of linear layouts so if its that case then you need to ```findViewById(R.id.ln1);findViewById(R.id.ln2);```... instead of just alone ln1,ln2,... them to can be used as a  View.

Comment: I have renewed your code in my post Edit section. hope it'll helo you.

Comment: Hi Amir, once again thank you for your concern. 1. Yeah it was 'i' only typo mistake in comments but not in code and I have given code correctly. 2. I'll update the code with ViewById and let you know. 3. If condition should be required as per code requirement. I'm really sorry I can't able to post complete code as this code is too much lengthy around 8k lines. So I couldn't able to post complete code. Due to this lengthy code, I have given the part of the code where I want and can able to shorten this lengthy code. GET BACK TO YOU..

Comment: be sure this is gonna work but my question is are those ```linear_layout1``` and others, 
 Id's property of LinearLayout in yours.XML file?

Comment: Yeah you are right, those are .xml ID's. Sorry, I forgot to say about ID's.

Comment: No luck. Tried with edited code but same issue I'm facing as I informed in previous comment. However, thank you for your patience and time you spent on this.